# Android http post send with different charset encoding

Tags: android, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

i've got a problem do a http post on android with german "umlaute" äöü. I am passing a json object to the method below and execute the returned ClientResource with post and the request entity in the returned client response. When I want to post something like { "foo":"bär" } the HttpClient sends something like { "foo":"b√§r" }.

Don't know why. What am I doing wrong.

```
public static ClientResource newPostRequest(Context context, String urn,
        JSONObject form) throws MissingAccessTokenException {

    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(uri + urn);

    StringRepresentation sr = new StringRepresentation(form.toString());
    sr.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    resource.getRequest().setEntity(sr);

    return resource;
}
```

**Update**

I used the default android http client (which is a apache http client I believe) and got the same error. So the problem might be located here. I try to implement another json parser (currently gson) and (if possible) another http client. Be back later...

**Update**

Gson is not the problem. I added a json String to the StringRepresentation and nothing changed.

**ANSWER**

Well that's an odd one. Maybe someone can clear this for me. I always asked myself, why *√§* where used and I figured out that translating the utf-8 *ä* leads to *√§*. Obviously my android phone did not use macroman, but my mac did. I therefor changed the text file encoding in eclipse, restarted eclipse and the tomcat server and it worked. Still the TCP/IP Monitor in eclipse uses mac roman which looks still wrong.   It was thereby a problem with my server, not with the restlet client on android. I just couldn't see it because the TCP/IP Monitor encoded everything in macroman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try calling [setCharacterSet(...)](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/representation/StringRepresentation.html#setCharacterSet%28org.restlet.data.CharacterSet%29) on your `StringRepresentation`? e.g.,

```
StringRepresentation sr = new StringRepresentation(form.toString());
sr.setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);
```

Comment: first, you mentioned HttpClient, but you are using Restlet. can you explain? second, how did you determine that that data is being sent incorrectly, as opposed to decoded incorrectly on the server?

Comment: Isn't Restlet using the DefaultHttpClient on Android? I started to monitor the server port for the incoming requests, that's how i determined what the client had send.

Comment: restlet *can* use HttpClient, but it does not necessarily use it (it sounds like in your case it is using it). regardless, since you are using restlet interfaces, you will need to solve the problem in the context of restlet.